# The same number of values, into & out of Tensor Flow NN?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am feeding a network an XY signal with peaks in it.  I can generate 10,000 sample signals.  Each signal has a random number of peaks.  Every time a signal is made, I save the # of peaks in the solution array.  The goal is to train the network to find the # of peaks based on the signal data.  So the input & output for this network is:

- X_Train: 2 x 100 x 10,000
- Y_Train: 1 x 10,000 x 1

But this draws the following error:

> ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
> x sizes: 2
> y sizes: 1
> Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.

Here is my code.

```
Data = DataMaker(100000,ScanSize,1)
Data.MakeLotsPks(10000)
Dims = Data.GetTensor().shape

XTrain = tf.cast(tf.convert_to_tensor(Data.GetTensor()),TensorDataType)
YTrain = tf.convert_to_tensor(Data.GetLables())

YTrain = tf.expand_dims(YTrain, 0)
YTrain = tf.expand_dims(YTrain, 2)

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_tensor=XTrain, input_shape=(2,ScanSize,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.Flatten())

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
               loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
               metrics=[keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])

model.fit(XTrain, YTrain,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=number_of_epoch,
          verbose=1)
```

Based on this error, it looks like this network needs the same number of values in as it does out.  Which does not make sense to me.  **Isn't the goal to classify complex data sets with simple tags? If so, why would the in/out tensors need the same # of values?** DNNs, CNNs and Flatten are all supposed to do the same thing. What concept am I missing here?

---

Edit.  I made the following changes:

```
filters = 3
k = 5              
strides = 1
padding = 'VALID'

# Setting up the model.
model = keras.Sequential()

# One input node.
model.add(InputLayer(input_tensor=XTrain, input_shape=(2,ScanSize,)))

# Filter the signal using Convolutional Layers.
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(10, filters, k, strides, padding))

# We want 1 or 0 for peaks or not peaks.
model.add(layers.Dense(20, activation="sigmoid"))

# The Output layer has to be 1 node to ensure that 1 vector is sent out.
model.add(layers.Dense(1))

# use binary cross entropy for the loss function  ==> number classification.
# sparse categorical cross-entropy ==> Classification based on Classes.

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
            loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
            metrics=[keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])

# Training Command
model.fit(XTrain, YTrain,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=number_of_epoch,
          verbose=1)
```

But this still draws the error:

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'

I tried a couple of different settings for padding = "VALID", "valid", 'valid', and 'VALID'.  I am sure I can figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You want to predict a single value (count) but the output of your model is not a single value (you have a dense layer with size 2). Your model should predict a single output. Also you are using sparse categorical cross-entropy which is for predicting a class, not a number.

An aside, I would try predicting the *locations* of the peaks instead of number of them, and simple count them up later. Counts are a kind of metric that is typically not a good target for training.

So say your input has size `[2,100]`. You want to predict the locations of the peaks - 0 = not a peak, 1 = peak. The output would then be size `[100]`.

How to do this:

- Use a couple of convolutions with size [2, K] and padding = 'valid' where k is the size of the kernel that makes sense for your data. E.g. K = 5 will look at 5 values centred on a value in the input signal, 2 x K = 5 convs will look at 13 and so on.
- use sigmoid activation to predict a single value between 0 and 1 for each location
- use a vector size [100] for the target where 0 is no peak, and 1 is peak
- use binary cross entropy for the loss function